# How to kill this python process opened using subprocess.pOpen() in Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess, kill-process

The code below to kill a process opened using `subprocess.Popen()` works on Linux.

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

# The os.setsid() is passed in the argument preexec_fn so
# it's run after the fork() and before  exec() to run the shell.
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                       shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid) 

os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)  # Send the signal to all the process groups
```

Unfortunately, it does not work on Windows. The process refused to be killed. How to modify the code such that the process can be killed on Windows?

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.8 on Anaconda.

Comment: `os.killpg()` is only available on Unix. Try passing `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` to `subprocess.Popen()` and calling `os.kill(pro.pid, signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)`.

Comment: @aaron `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` doesn't work on Windows. `signal.SIGTERM` works, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `subprocess.Popen.terminate()` TO TERMINATE A SUBPROCESS